# Twig- Include Template from other Directory

Tags: twig

Is it possible to include a template with `{% include %}` which is outside from the template path defined with:

```
$template = $twig->loadTemplate('example.tpl');
```

I'm asking it because this line doesn't work:

```
{% include '.../example/navbar_left.tpl' %}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it's not possible using `Twig_Loader_Filesystem`, because it explicitly rejects template names which have `..` inside. This can be verified into the definition of function `validateName($name)` inside file `Twig/lib/Twig/Loader/Filesystem.php`.

The only clean solution I can think of, if you need to access a template outside the path, is to [create your own loader](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/api.html#create-your-own-loader).

A workaround that does work, is defining a symbolic link inside the folder actually registered with `Twig_Loader_Filesystem`, pointing to the directory you want to access. Be **careful** with this method, point the link to a safe place.

Comment: Is the /app/ directory outside of the scope of `include`?

Answer (score 5):

You can add more paths by following :
https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/templating/namespaced_paths.html

**config.yml**

```
# Twig Configuration
twig:
  paths:
    '%kernel.root_dir%/../src/AppBundle/Resources/views': AppBundle
    '%kernel.root_dir%/../web/': 'WEB_DIR_DIST' #your new custom path
```

**someFile.html.twig**

```
<script>{{ source('@WEB_DIR_DIST' ~ 'custom.js') }}</script>
```

Comment: This should be the right answer. It is not a workaround and supports the use case that is mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 4):

You can add your path to the Twig loader (Filesystem loader)
see last reply from Fabien (addPath method is what you need)
https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/1912

Answer (score 2):

you can add the second path to your twig.yaml (symfony 4.4)

```
twig:
    paths:
        - '%kernel.project_dir%/templates'
        - '%kernel.project_dir%/example'
```

Then just use the name `{% include 'navbar_left.tpl' %}`

Answer (score 1):

It is possible through symlink.

## Example for Symfony3

from `src/AppBundle/Resources/views/Admin`

Ubuntu:

```
ln -s ./../../../../../web/admin/_index-import-body.html index-import-body.html.twig
```

Windows:

```
mklink index-import-body.html.twig ./../../../../../web/admin/_index-import-body.html
```

Then like always include that `index-import-body.html.twig` in twig file

```
{% include '@App/Admin/index-import-body.html.twig' %}
```